# Merge 2 facts in cube?

Tags: schema, pentaho, olap-cube, mondrian

Is it possible to merge 2 facts tables to create a cube in a Mondrian schema
example the case of  **sales** and **cost** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is usual to have both sales and cost measures in one fact table and add them both as measures to one cube.

If you cannot have them both in the same fact table, they need to have common dimension(s), so they can be joined together in [Virtual Cube](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php#Virtual_cubes) (up to Mondrian 3.8). Time dimension is usual:

DHW

- **Table fact_sales:** `date_key, ..., sales`
- **Table fact_cost:** `date_key, ..., cost`
- **Table dim_date:** `date_key, day_of_month, month, year, ...`

Mondrian OLAP schema

- **Dimension [Date]:** table `dim_date`, primary key column `date_key`, level year `year`, level month ...
- **Cube [Sales]:** table `fact_sales`, dimension [Date] usage `date_key`, measure `sales`
- **Cube [Cost]:** table `fact_sales`, dimension [Date] usage `date_key`, measure `cost`
- **Virtual Cube [Sales and Cost]:** virtual cube dimension `[Date]`, virtual cube measure `[Sales.sales]`, virtual cube measure `[Cost.cost]`

Comment: Hi ,
is it possible to add the dimensions employee and the thing is that he is working on different department through calender  (also a dimension )

Comment: That leads to implement `employee` as a `Slowly Changing Dimension type 2` (SCD type 2). Every employee dimension record needs to have "validity period" (effective_date, expiration_date OR valid_from, valid_to pair). This means you have multiple employee records for `one concrete employee` within the dimension. Next you need to ensure the fact tables have correct references to employee dimension records according to fact-record-determining date in compare to employee validity period.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
I have already implemented but I have a problem with the measure : I get a wrong result

Answer (score 4):

If you can use Mondrian 4 you can specify the exact SQL statement that should be executed to retrieve data for fact table. Therefore you can do the join on the database level, like below:

```
 <PhysicalSchema>
    <Query alias="FACT">
        <ExpressionView>
            <SQL dialect="generic">
                select f.*, f2.measure_2 from FACT f INNER JOIN FACT2 f2 ON f.id = f2.fact_id
            </SQL>
        </ExpressionView>
    </Query>
</PhysicalSchema>
```

See the full example here:
http://thejavatar.com/mondrian-4-in-pentaho-bi-server/